# $elemMatch doesn't work on nested documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Stack Overflow!

I have a very strange problem with using **$elemMatch in MongoDB**. I added multiple documents to a collection. Some of these documents were added using **import feature in MongoDB Compass** (Add Data -> Import File -> JSON) and some of them were added using **insertMany()**.
Here is an example structure of a single document:

```
{
    "id": "1234567890",
    "date": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "contents": {
        "0": {
            "content": {
                "id": "1111111111",
                "name": "Name 1"
            }
        },
        "1": {
            "content": {
                "id": "2222222222",
                "name": "Name 2"
            }
        },
        "2": {
            "content": {
                "id": "3333333333",
                "name": "Name 3"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is, when I use the following find query using this filter:

```
{date: "<some_date_here>", "contents": {
    $elemMatch: {
        "content.id": <some_id_here>
    }
}}
```

**ONLY** documents that were imported from MongoDB Compass are showing up. Documents that were added by Mongosh or by NodeJS driver (doesn't matter), **do NOT show up**.

Am I missing something obvious here? What should I do in order to make all documents in a collection (that matches filter) to show up?

Simple filters that do not include $elemMatch work well and all documents that match the filtering rules show up. Problem seems to be with $elemMatch.

I tried adding the same batch of documents using different methods but only direct importing a JSON file in MongoDB Compass make them appear using a filter mentioned above.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`$elemMatch` if for matching array , and in this case you don't have array
first you should convert `contents` object to array and then check the query for example id with `filter` and use `match` to find all doc that have specific data and size of new filters array

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newField": {
        "$objectToArray": "$contents"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newField": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$newField",
          "as": "z",
          "cond": {
            $eq: [
              "$$z.v.content.id",
              "1111111111"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "newField": {
        $size: "$newField"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {$and:[ {newField: {
        $gt: 0
      }},{date:{$gt:Date}}]}
     
    
  },
  {$project:{
    contents:1,
    date:1,
    id:1,
  }}
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/pue4QPp1dYR
in mongoplayground I don't add filter of date